# How can I trigger a Python script from Bitbucket Webhooks?

Tags: python, bitbucket-server

I want to execute a Python script each time a pull-request is merged. I am using Bitbucket and I saw that it has a web-hook option, where I can put an URL and it will call that URL.

Is there a way I can directly call the python script like

```
someurl.com/script.py
```

or will I need to build a "bridge" inbetween?

I also have Jenkins available as a tool, but how can I trigger a Jenkins job from the webhook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already were able to do this. I used a Jenkins job that gets executed when the URL has been requested. At the same time the Jenkins job executes a bash script when called.

Comment: Could you walk me through how you did this in more detail?